# Double solid angle integration with integrand only dependent on relative angle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose one has an integral of the following form,
$$
\int \text{d} \Omega_{1} \text{d} \Omega_{2} f(\gamma).
$$
Where gamma is the relative angle between $(\theta_1, \phi_1)$ and $(\theta_2, \phi_2)$,
$$
\cos \gamma = \cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 + \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)
$$
Based on symmetry arguments one could argue that as the integrand is only dependent the relative angle, we can fix $\Omega_1$, integrate over $\Omega_2$, and multiply the result with $4 \pi$ to compensate for fixing $\Omega_1$. Additionally we can argue that if we fix $\Omega_1$ along the $z$ axis the integration over $\phi_2$ just gives a factor $2 \pi$. So we have,
$$
\int \text{d} \Omega_{1} \text{d} \Omega_{2} f(\gamma) = 8 \pi^{2} \int \sin \gamma \, \text{d}\gamma f(\gamma). 
$$
However I fail to make an explicit mathematical derivation of the above reasoning. If I try to write the solid angle differentials in terms of $\gamma$ i get quite lengthy and ugly looking expressions.

Comment: I think you should explain what you consider "an explicit mathematical derivation". To me, your argument constitutes just that.

Comment: I was just wondering how would one do this derivation without being "clever" and attempt a transformation of variables from $\theta_1 \phi_1, \theta_2 \phi_2$ to $\gamma + $ other variables that will be integrated out to give $8 \pi^2$. Because I do not see how you would do that. So without using symmetry arguments but using only basic transformations of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. In case someone else has/will have the same problem I'm posting it.

Suppose we have an integral which looks like,
\begin{align*}
 \int \textrm{d} \Omega_1 \int \textrm{d} \Omega_2 \, f( \gamma ),
\end{align*}
where $\gamma$ is the relative angle between $ \Omega_1$ and $ \Omega_2$ given by $\cos \gamma = \cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 + \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1)$. Now we can make the following reasoning based on symmetry. As the integrand is only depend on the relative angle $y$ we can fix $(\theta_1, \phi_1)$ at the $z$-axis. The integration over $\phi_2$ simply gives $2 \pi$ while $\theta_2 \equiv \gamma$. Now to compensate for fixing $(\theta_1, \phi_1)$ we have to multiply the result with $4 \pi$. So we get,
\begin{align*}
 \int \textrm{d} \Omega_1 \int \textrm{d} \Omega_2 \, f( \gamma ) = \int \textrm{d}\theta_1 \sin \theta_1 \int \textrm{d}\phi_1 \int \textrm{d} \sin \theta_2 \int \textrm{d} \phi_2 \, f( \gamma ) = 8 \pi^2 \int \textrm{d} \gamma \sin(\gamma) f(\gamma).
\end{align*}
But what about making this a hard proof using only transformations of variables? Let's begin. We introduce the following transformation of variables,
\begin{align*}
 \{ \theta_1, \phi_1, \theta_2, \phi_2 \} \rightarrow \{ \theta_1, \phi_1, \gamma, \omega \}
\end{align*}
With $\gamma$ the relative angle and $\omega$ a rotation angle around the $ \theta_1, \phi_1$-direction (which obviously preserves $\gamma$, or $\gamma$ and $\omega$ are independent).
First we construct the expressions for the new variables in terms of the old variables
\begin{align*}
 \theta_1 &= \theta_1 \\
 \phi_1 &= \phi_1 \\
 \cos \gamma &= \cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 + \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \\
 \sin \omega &= \frac{ \sin \theta_2 \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\sin \gamma}  
\end{align*}
The Jacobian is given by,
\begin{align*}
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c c c c}
  \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \omega} \\
  \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \omega} \\
  \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \omega} \\
  \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \phi_2} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \omega} \\
 \end{array}
 \right) =
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c c c c}
  1 & 0 & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \omega} \\
  0 & 1 & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \omega} \\
  0 & 0 & \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \omega} \\
  0 & 0 & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \gamma} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \omega} \\
 \end{array}
 \right)
 = \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \gamma}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \omega} - \frac{\partial \theta_2}{\partial \omega}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial \gamma}
\end{align*}
The expression for $\theta_2$ and $\phi_2$ in function of $\gamma$ and $\omega$ do not appear to be easily computable. Let's take instead the inverse transformation $ \{ \theta_1, \phi_1, \gamma, \omega \} \rightarrow \{ \theta_1, \phi_1, \theta_2, \phi_2 \}$ and invert the jacobian afterwards.
The Jacobian of the inverse transformation is given by,
\begin{align*}
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c c c c}
  \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial \theta_1}{\partial \phi_2} \\
  \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial  \phi_1}{\partial \phi_2} \\
  \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} \\
  \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} \\
 \end{array}
 \right) =
 \left(
 \begin{array}{c c c c}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} \\
  \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_1} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_1} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} & \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} \\
 \end{array}
 \right)
 = \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2}
\end{align*}
Let's calculate the partial derivatives one by one,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} = \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \cos \gamma} \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} = - \frac{1}{\sin \gamma} \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} = \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \cos \gamma} \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} = - \frac{1}{\sin \gamma} \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \sin \omega} \frac{\partial \sin \omega}{\partial \theta_2} &=  \frac{1}{\cos \omega} \frac{\partial \sin \omega}{\partial \theta_2} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\cos \omega} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_2} \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\sin \gamma} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \left( \cos \theta_2 \sin \gamma - \sin \theta_2 \frac{\partial \sin \gamma }{ \partial \theta_2} \right) \\
&= \frac{\sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \left( \cos \theta_2 \sin \gamma - \sin \theta_2 \frac{\partial \sin \gamma }{ \partial \cos \gamma} \frac{ \partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \right) \\
&= \frac{\sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \left( \cos \theta_2 \sin \gamma + \sin \theta_2 \cot \gamma \frac{ \partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \right)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} = \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \sin \omega} \frac{\partial \sin \omega}{\partial \phi_2} &=  \frac{1}{\cos \omega} \frac{\partial \sin \omega}{\partial \phi_2} \\
&= \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\cos \omega} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_2} \frac{\sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\sin \gamma}\\
&= \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\cos \omega \sin^2 \gamma} \left( \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \sin \gamma - \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \frac{\partial \sin \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\right) \\
&= \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\cos \omega \sin^2 \gamma} \left( \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \sin \gamma + \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \cot \gamma \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\right) 
\end{align*}
So the total expression becomes,
\begin{multline*}
\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} = - \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}\frac{\sin \theta_2}{\cos \omega \sin^3 \gamma} \left( \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \sin \gamma + \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \cot \gamma \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\right) \\
+ \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} \frac{\sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1)}{\cos \omega \sin^{3} \gamma} \left( \cos \theta_2 \sin \gamma + \sin \theta_2 \cot \gamma \frac{ \partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \right) \\
= \frac{1}{\ \cos \omega \sin^{3} \gamma} \left( - \sin \theta_2 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \sin \gamma \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} - \sin \theta_2 \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \cot \gamma \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \right.\\ 
+ \left. \cos \theta_2 \sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1) \sin \gamma \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} + \sin \theta_2 \sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1) \cot \gamma \frac{ \partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} \right) \\
= \frac{1}{\ \cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \left( \cos \theta_2 \sin(\phi_2 - \phi_1) \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} - \sin \theta_2 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} \right).
\end{multline*}
With,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \theta_2} &= - \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 + \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1 ), \\
 \frac{\partial \cos \gamma}{\partial \phi_2} &= - \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \sin (\phi_2 - \phi_1),
\end{align*}
we get,
\begin{multline}
 \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} = \frac{1}{\ \cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \Big( - \cos \theta_2  \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \sin^{2} (\phi_2 - \phi_1) \\
  + \sin^{2} \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) - \sin \theta_2  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 \cos^{2} (\phi_2 - \phi_1 ) \Big) \\
  = \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\ \cos \omega \sin^{2} \gamma} \left( \sin \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) -  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 \right)
\end{multline}
Using the standard cosine rule we find,
\begin{align*}
 \cos \theta_2 = \cos \theta_1 \cos \gamma + \sin \theta_1 \sin \gamma \cos \omega \Rightarrow \cos \omega = \frac{\cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1 \cos \gamma}{\sin \theta_1 \sin \gamma}
\end{align*}
Hence we get,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi_2} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \phi_2}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta_2} &= \frac{\sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2}{\  \sin \gamma} \left( \frac{ \sin \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) -  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 }{ \cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1 \cos \gamma} \right) \\
&=\frac{\sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2}{\  \sin \gamma} \left( \frac{ \sin \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) -  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 }{ \cos \theta_2 - \cos^{2} \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos ( \phi_2 - \phi_1)} \right) \\
&=\frac{\sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2}{\  \sin \gamma} \left( \frac{ \sin \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) -  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 }{ \cos \theta_2 \sin^{2} \theta_1 - \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \cos ( \phi_2 - \phi_1)} \right) \\
&= - \frac{\sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2}{\  \sin \gamma \sin \theta_1 } \left( \frac{ \sin \theta_2  \cos \theta_1 \cos (\phi_2 - \phi_1) -  \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2 }{ \sin \theta_2 \cos \theta_1 \cos ( \phi_2 - \phi_1) - \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_2   } \right) \\
&= - \frac{\sin \theta_2}{\  \sin \gamma }
\end{align*}
Now we have derived the Jacobian of the inverse transformation. The jacobian of the original transformation is given by
\begin{align*}
 |J| = \frac{ \sin \gamma }{\sin \theta_2 }
\end{align*}
Hence we get,
\begin{align*}
 \int \textrm{d}\theta_1 \sin \theta_1 \int \textrm{d}\phi_1 \int \textrm{d} \sin \theta_2 \int \textrm{d} \phi_2 \, f( \gamma ) &\rightarrow \int_{0}^{\pi} \textrm{d}\theta_1 \sin \theta_1 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \textrm{d}\phi_1 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \textrm{d} \omega  \int_{0}^{\pi} \textrm{d} \gamma \sin \theta_2 \, \frac{ \sin \gamma }{\sin \theta_2 } f( \gamma )  \\
 &= 8 \pi^{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \textrm{d} \gamma \, \sin (\gamma) \,  f( \gamma ) \,\,\, \square.
\end{align*}
Which is exactly the result we expected.